# How elemMatch on multiple arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 different arrays, like below:

```
id: 100,
a: [
   {date: '2018-09-03', aa: 0},
   {date: '2018-09-04', aa: 0},
   {date: '2018-09-05', aa: 0},
],
b: [
   {date: '2018-09-03', bb: 0},
   {date: '2018-09-04', bb: 0},
   {date: '2018-09-05', aa: 0},
]
```

I need to increment **aa** by *10* and **bb** by *20*. So I am doing like that:

```
{$and: [
    {id: 100},
    {a: {$elemMatch: {date: '2018-09-04'}}},
    {b: {$elemMatch: {date: '2018-09-04'}}},
]}, {
    $inc: {
        "a.$.aa": 10,
        "b.$.bb": 20
    }
}
```

The problem is that elemMatches not work, they are taking first elements of arrays. In this example: '2018-09-03' instead of '2018-09-04'.

Comment: strange, testing it work perfectly for me. why do you think both $elemMatch don't work?did you try with find method?

Comment: Yes, it works, I think the problem was in ObjectId specification.

Comment: Don't understand. Where do you have ObjectId?

Comment: In real example I was matching {_id: "5b2105df462336023be8b386"}, and elemMatch was failing, then I changed to ObjectId

Comment: Ok. All's good for you now, or do you still need any help for your query? If so, please provide real samples (with objectId) and your complete query.

Comment: No, it not works. So it increments first element of array and not matches exact element of array

Comment: ok, please provide real samples (with objectId) and your complete query

Answer (score 0):

$elemMatch is not the good way, you must use [$[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) with arrayFilters option. This should work :

```
db['01'].update(
{id:100},
{$inc: {
        "a.$[elementA].aa": 10,
        "b.$[elementB].bb": 20
    }}
,{arrayFilters:[{"elementA.date":"2018-09-03"},{"elementB.date":"2018-09-03"}],
  multi:true}
)
```

Hope it helps